# How can I get user's IP address using NginX + Next.JS + Apollo GraphQL

Tags: nginx, graphql, next.js, apollo-client

I'm using next.js app, graphql server, and nginx.

I have to grep client ip address.

So in my nginx conf file, I added

```
 ...

 location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;     # next.js server (3000)
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

location /graphql {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/graphql;        # graphql server (4000)
}
```

And In my graphql, I added

```
const ip = context.req.header('X-Real-IP')
console.log(ip)
```

Now I can get client IP very well !

But, the problem is when user doing SSR (refresh page)

The ip address is `127.0.0.1 or localhost`

**How could I get real ip address even if user is in server side rendering?**

Comment: Can you share the code that makes the GQL request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your Next.js makes a server to server call, therefore you get the localhost ip.

You need to attach the user ip that you get in Next.js to the request it makes to the GQL server.

Comment: Yes. I did it.!